# Array of objects sort works on way on Chrome and the other on Firefox with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, sorting, firefox

I have a necessity to order an array of objects using another list order, but here's the catch the strings on the list only fulfill partially a particular attribute from the object.

So I need to check the object *'name'* attribute to verify if it's in the order as shown in the *toSort* variable.

Basically, I have something like this:

```
var toSort = ['Engeneering', 'Design', 'Implementation', 'Test', 'Homologation'];

var unsortedList = [
{id: 1, name: 'Rework for Test phase'}, 
{id: 2, name: 'Rework for Homologation phase'},
{id: 3, name: 'Rework for Design phase'},
{id: 4, name: 'Excluding Alteration on Implementation phase'}]
```

I need a function to order as shown in the toSort variable
Like this:

```
var sortedList = [
{id: 3, name: 'Rework for Design phase'},
{id: 4, name: 'Excluding Alteration on Implementation phase'},
{id: 1, name: 'Rework for Test phase'}, 
{id: 2, name: 'Rework for Homologation phase'}];
```

And I did it in two ways. This one works on Firefox:

```
function orderByPhase(unsortedList) {
 var sortedlist = [];
 for(var i = 0; i <= toSort.lenght; i++) {
    sortedList = unsortedList.sort(a , b) {
      return a.nome.includes(toSort[i]) && !b.nome.includes(toSort[i]) ? 1 : -1;
    }
 }
return sortedList;
}
```

But it doesn't work on Chrome. This one below, Works on Chrome, but it doesn't on Firefox:

```
function orderByPhase(unsortedList) {
 var sortedlist = [];
 for(var i = 0; i <= toSort.lenght; i++) {
    sortedList = unsortedList.sort(a , b) {
        var aFirst = a.nome.includes(this.fases[i]) ? 1 : -1;
        var bFirst = 0;
        bFirst = aFirst && !b.nome.includes(this.fases[i]) ? 1 : -1;
        return bFirst;
    }
 }
return sortedList;
}
```

Can someone help me find a middle ground here?

Comment: `but it doesn't on Firefox` Define "doesn't work". Does it raise an exception? If so, what is the content of that exception?

Comment: spelling of `lenght`... and `i` can be equal to it? Also `sort` takes one argument at most, and that should be a callback when provided. None of this can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

- `lenght` is mispelled in both versions, so the loop will not iterate at all
- `i` should not increase up and equal to `length`, as that will lead to an undefined `this.phases[i]` reference
- Not sure what `unsortedList.sort(a, b)` was intended to do: `a` and `b` are undefined, and `sort` takes only one (optional) argument. If there is an argument it should be a function. Maybe you intended to write an arrow function like this: `sort((a,b) =>`?
- A `sort` callback function should be able to return 0 when there is no reason to enforce a certain order.
- Even if this could be made to work, it is not efficient at all, since you call `sort` in every iteration, which would give this a time complexity of *O(mnlogn)* where *m* is the length of `toSort` (which I assume is the same array as `this.phases`), and *n* the size of the array to sort.

I would suggest first to map the input array to enrich it with the index each value belongs to: the index in the `toSort` array. Only then call `sort` on that, with a callback that will compare those indexes. Then finally remove those indexes again with a `map` call.

Here is an implementation:

```js
var toSort = ['Engeneering', 'Design', 'Implementation', 'Test', 'Homologation'];

var unsortedList = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Rework for Test phase'}, 
    {id: 2, name: 'Rework for Homologation phase'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Rework for Design phase'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Excluding Alteration on Implementation phase'}
];

var sorted = unsortedList.map(o => [o, toSort.findIndex(word => o.name.includes(word))])
                         .sort(([,a], [,b]) => a - b)
                         .map(([o]) => o);
console.log(sorted);
```

This has a time complexity of *O(nm + nlogn)*.